# why kinematic 2D rigidbody collider overlap with another kinematic 2D rigidbody collider using rigdbody2D.cast?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying ground collision of kinematic bodies using rigidbody2D.cast. Player and ground collider overlap with each other.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ForceMethod : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Vector2 worldGravity;
    [SerializeField] float downCastDistance = 0.05f;
    Vector2 startingVelocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
    RaycastHit2D[] hits = new RaycastHit2D[2];
    Rigidbody2D rb;

   void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        rb.Cast(Vector2.down, hits, downCastDistance);
       
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + startingVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
        startingVelocity += worldGravity * Time.deltaTime;
        if (hits[0].collider.name == "Ground")
        {
            rb.MovePosition(rb.position);
        }
    }
}
```

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1JX2.png)
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCt8C.png)

Comment: I'd say because there is nothing preventing it from doing so ... `rb.MovePosition(rb.position)` just tries to move it to the same position it is already in and `rb.MovePosition(rb.position + startingVelocity * Time.deltaTime);` moves it downwards ...

Comment: In general please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now!

Answer (score 0):

`rb.MovePosition(rb.position);`
does nothing, since moves the rb in its current same position.

What you want to do probably is check *before* moving the rb if the cast hits the ground, but cast in the fixed update as well, and not of a fixed downCastDistance but cast by the same distance the rb will travel downward (which is startingVelocity * Time.deltaTime). If it doesn't hit then go down normally as you did, if it does, move the rb to the highest position between the normal fall update and the position of the point where the raycast hit (which is at ground level):

```
//FixedUpdate()

float currTravelDistance = startingVelocity.y * Time.deltaTime;
rb.Cast(Vector2.down, hits, Mathf.Abs(currTravelDistance));
if (hits[0].collider.name == "Ground")
    {
        rb.position.y = Mathf.Max((rb.position + currTravelDistance).y, hits[0].point.y);
    }
else {
    rb.MovePosition(rb.position + currTravelDistance);
}
```

also since this moves the rb exactly on the ground, if the rb's center is in the middle of the sprite, move it up by the distance from the sprite's "feet" to its center.
Finally if the player hits the ground you also need to reset to 0 startingVelocity